# How to set the number of iterations in PySpark Word2vec model?

Tags: python, apache-spark, word2vec

My code:

```
 word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize = 100, minCount = 100, inputCol = 'token', 
 outputCol = 'word2vec', seed=123)
```

I tried the keyword numIterations,
but it is invalid

From Pyspark Documentation:

```
setNumIterations(int numIterations)
```

Sets number of iterations (default: 1), which should be smaller than or equal to the number of partitions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked the PySpark docs?

Comment: Yes. In the Docs:

setNumIterations(int numIterations)
Sets number of iterations (default: 1), which should be smaller than or equal to number of partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter seems to be `maxIter`: give that a try.

```
  final val maxIter: IntParam = new IntParam(this, "maxIter", 
     "maximum number of iterations (>= 0)", ParamValidators.gtEq(0))
```

Comment: @JerryGeorge Thanks for accepting! You put me over the top !  (20002 reputation now)